# is there a shell command can change SPI clock for raspberry pi zero?

Tags: bash, shell, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi-zero

I would like to write a bash file to light up an OLED screen with SSD1306 driver, with below code I can send the SPI commands to the screen but seems the CLK is supper fast so the SSD1306 doesn't work, is there a way to change the SCLK for SPI interface(like set to 4Mhz) in the shell? I am using Raspberry Pi Zero W.

```
echo -ne $cmd > /dev/spidev0.0
```

Comment: more appropriate to https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com .  Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following for 3.9MHz:

```
echo -ne "\x06\x04" > /sys/class/spi_master/spi0/of_node/spi-max-frequency
```

Table for different speed deviders you can find [here](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#spi-overview%23driver)